# Getting item position at onclick of recyclerview in Android(Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am retrieving images from the firebase database into my recyclerview and it's all fine. `myRef` is the database reference variable and its value is `("HomeLayout/04")`.

Now when the cardview is clicked, I want to get the full Database Reference i.e.
value of `myRef` should be taken upto `("HomeLayout/04/image")`.

Any help / ideas..?[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MateriaViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Materia model) {
    DocumentSnapshot r = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position);
    r.getReference().getPath();
}
```